# Chromebook cannot connect to local server/ private network address ("This site cannot be reached")

Tags: linux, networking, chromebook, xampp, google-chrome-os

I need some networking and chromebook help...

I bought a Chromebook,...
I connected it to the local wifi network.,. this is composed of My main computer (web server #1) and a raspberry pi running pi-hole (web server #2) on the network, and my Chromebook.

**Typology:**

- Computer #1 (main PC used as a part-time web server for web projects)// http://192.168.1.142/
- Raspi used for pi-hole // http://192.168.1.104/ with a web server (port 80) and ssh (port 3782)
- Chromebook running using port 192.168.1.109

**Anyway,** I can connect fine to the pi-hole (http://192.168.1.104/) from the Chromebook but cannot connect to the other server ("main computer" / http://192.168.1.142/).

In the chrome browser, I get the error "This site Cannot be reached" // "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE"

Strange as it's connected to the network using that private IP address...
I checked the firewall ("ufw") and allowed ports 80 and 443.. however, that didn't work. Then I disabled the firewall entirely.. this was unsuccessful; also.

So I can only connect to this server from the actual computer running it when I need to connect to it from the ChromOS Chromebook.

Not sure if this is relevant but the IP address associated with the computer [chromeos/chromebook] from the "ip a" command shows that interface "eth0@if6" is 100.115.92.195/28.. not sure why.,.. might be relevant though .

Ta.

PS when running "curl -I 192.168.1.142" to probe for HTTP header requests from the PI [ssh] (to webserver/computer #1) I get "No route to host" returned (on the terminal). BTW, this curl command from the computer to itself returns header information. - just thought I would include that.

*Just to note*: the webserver needs to be seen by hosts on all the network not just itself.

Also, i must say that ping from the chromebook and the pi are both replying.

---

**UPDATE**: I'm using XAMPP on computer #1 for the webserver. Anyway, i changed the configuration so that the "conf" file (httpd.conf) is et to "Listen 192.168.1.142:1337" rather than "Listen: 80". Though still cannot access this server from said port.

Double checked firewall and it's not running.

**UPDATE**: Ran an nmap scan on the host and it's not showing a webserver at all. Carried out on both pi and chromebook machines.

**UPDATE**: Rebooted router. No success.

**UPDATE**: Tried accessing on my phone but getting the same problem "This site cannot be reached".. ("http://192.168.1.142:8080 is unreachable"). Note: moved port back to 80.

Comment: Do a quick `netstat -an` on the webserver and check that xampp is actually listening nicely like `TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0`, and doesn't show a specific ip or 127.0.0.1. chrome os apps only see that virtual interface as part of the sandboxing. What operating system is xampp running on? it doesn't seem like the issue has anything to do with the other clients

Comment: Hi. This is the output from "sudo netstat -plnt" https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/Eoi5bT07X6ig.png Hope URL's are allowed here. The server is running (computer #1) linux mint

Comment: Thought disabling ipv6 and restarting would help.. now looks like this... https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/WXGDRMq2c9YB.png?o=1 (note: changed port from 80 to 8080 also)

Comment: Thanks. I went into Synaptic Package Manager and removed everything named "ufw" / "gufw" and some other third party firewall stuff that I didnt even realise I had installed. Anyway, turned out to be a firewall issue i guess and now works. Thanks.